# How to display html:text using <logic:iterate> for List<String> in Struts1.1

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jsp-tags, struts-1

I have a `List<String>` in my `ActionForm` which has to be represented as a text field in the JSP page using `Struts1.1`

```
 List<String> url=new ArrayList<String>();
 public List<String> getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(List<String> url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
```

The Following is the code that I have used inside JSP page

```
 <logic:iterate id="urlIterate" name="pForm" property="url">
    <html:text property="?????" name="urlIterate"/>
    </logic:iterate>
```

`<html:text>` is working good for `List<SomeClass>` because property can be point to a particular variable and `List<SomeClass>` acts as a bean.

```
 <logic:iterate id="listUserId" property="listUsers" name="pForm">
 <html:text name="listUserId" property="username"/>
 </logic:iterate>
```

where listUsers is a `List` with `User` type of class 
private List listUsers;
 In `property="username"` `username` is a variable inside `User` Class

For `List<String>`

```
<bean:write name="urlIterate" />
```

I don't find issue  to display as a text using `<bean:write>` since it has only `name` attribute.
But to use `<html:text>` we need to add another mandatory attribute `property`.

Can any one please help me out. what value to be used for `property='?????'` in order to make the `html:text` to work correctly.

Thanks in advance

Providing more code..
JSP page for UI.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<html:form action="/plist">
<h1>Struts &lt;logic:iterate&gt; example</h1>

  <logic:iterate property="listMsg" name="pForm"  id="listMsgId">
    <p>
    List Messages </p> <html:text property="listMsgId" indexed="true"/> 

</logic:iterate>

 <html:submit/>

  </html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Action Class:

```
public class PrintMsgAction extends Action {


    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
                throws Exception {

        List<OptionsListCollection> listoptions=new ArrayList<OptionsListCollection>();

                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    listoptions.add(new OptionsListCollection("Option"+i, "OptionValue"+i));    
                }

                List<String> listMsg = new ArrayList<String>();

                listMsg.add("Message A");
                listMsg.add("Message B");
                listMsg.add("Message C");
                listMsg.add("Message D");

                            PrintForm pForm=(PrintForm)form;
                pForm.setListMsg(listMsg);



                return mapping.findForward("plist");
            }
}
```

and ActionForm

```
public class PrintForm extends ActionForm{

    private List<String> listMsg;

    public List<String> getListMsg() {
        return listMsg;
    }
    public void setListMsg(List<String> listMsg) {
        this.listMsg = new ArrayList<String>();

        this.listMsg = listMsg;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [struts-logic-iterate-example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-logic-iterate-example/). Your code should read -

```
 <logic:iterate id="urlIterate" name="pForm" >
    <html:text property="urlIterate" indexed="true"/>
 </logic:iterate>
```

Comment: Hi Farrel, I have tried using `property="url"` before and got an exception, `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property url of bean urlIterate`. The link you have specified is regarding `<bean:write>` but not `<html:text>`.

Comment: And now I have tried your code by removing `property="url"` in `<logic:iterate>` of my code and still getting an exception saying. `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot create iterator for this collection`

Comment: Can you add your form?

Comment: Sorry i hadnt accounted for differences between html:text and bean:write

Comment: Can you specify which form should I add  ActionForm Class that I created or Code of JSP Form

Comment: Can you check against this example on setting up a struts project - http://www.raistudies.com/struts-1/login-form-with-struts-1/? You dont provide enough info in your question

Comment: Hi Farrel, I have gone through the link you have specified. Unlike that  code here the usage of `<logic:iterate> `  is making the implementation complex which I am not aware of.

Comment: I have tried the changes wiht your edited code and I am getting a new exception. `No getter method for property urlIterate of bean org.apache.struts.taglib.html.BEAN` are you aware of this exception?

Comment: Hi Farrel, I have added classes and jsp code.. Could you have a look at the code and reply